# Avoid hydrateRoot() in next.js on shallow client navigation

Tags: next.js

Consider this example app:

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

export default function Home() {
  const router = useRouter()

  return (
    <>
      <main>
        <Link href="?a=1">Link 1</Link>
        <Link href="?a=2">Link 2</Link>

        <div onClick={() => router.push('?a=1', undefined, {shallow: true})}>router.push 1</div>
        <div onClick={() => router.push('?a=2', undefined, {shallow: true})}>router.push 2</div>
        
        <div onClick={() => window.history.pushState({}, '', '?a=1')}>pushState 1</div>
        <div onClick={() => window.history.pushState({}, '', '?a=2')}>pushState 2</div>
      </main>
    </>
  )
}
```

When clicking Link 1, Link 2, router.push 1, router.push 2 the Root is re-rendered because of `hydrateRoot()` if we look in the React profiler:

[image: profiler]

Can we somehow avoid the `hydrateRoot()` to get triggered on shallow client side navigations?

When pressing pushState 1 and pushState 2 the `hydrateRoot()` is not triggered.

When handling url/route state in an external store (eg. Zustand), I don't want this unnecessary re-render to happen.

Comment: Looking to solve the same issue. In my case, I have it such that clicking on a tab in a tab group executes a `push()` to update the URL, but this `push()` also causes the `hydrateRoot()` commit, which is responsible for the app-wide re-render that slows down the app considerably.